# How to save hash values into a CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, nokogiri

I have a CSV with one column that I like to save all my hash values on it. I am using nokogiri sax to parse a xml document and then save it to a CSV. I am getting the xml-value like this: `@infodata[:academic] = @content.inspect` The hash have the following keys:

```
@infodata = {}
@infodata[:titles] = Array.new([])
@infodata[:identifier]  
@infodata[:typeOfLevel]
@infodata[:typeOfResponsibleBody]
@infodata[:type]
@infodata[:exact]
@infodata[:degree]
@infodata[:academic]
@infodata[:code]
@infodata[:text]
```

When I use this code right now to loop through the keys and save it to CSV:

```
def end_document
 CSV.open("info.csv", "wb") do |row|
  for key, val in @infodata
    row << [val,]
  end
 end
 puts "Finished..."     
end
```

The output that I get is:

```
"""avancerad"""
"""Ingen examen"""
"""uh"""
"""Arkivvetenskap""""Archival science"""
"""HIA80D"""
"""10.300"""
"""uoh"""
"""Arkivvetenskap rör villkoren för befintliga arkiv och modern arkivbildning med fokus på arkivarieyrkets arbetsuppgifter: bevara, tillgängliggöra och styra information. Under ett år behandlas bl a informations- och dokumenthantering, arkivredovisning, gallring, lagstiftning och arkivteori. I kursen ingår praktik, där man under handledning får arbeta med olika arkivarieuppgifter."""
"""statlig"""
"""60"""
```

How do I get the output like this:

```
"avancerad", "Ingen examen", "uh", "Arkivvetenskap", "Archival science", "HIA80D", 10.300,"uoh", "Arkivvetenskap rör villkoren för befintliga arkiv och modern arkivbildning med fokus på arkivarieyrkets arbetsuppgifter: bevara, tillgängliggöra och styra information. Under ett år behandlas bl a informations- och dokumenthantering, arkivredovisning, gallring, lagstiftning och arkivteori. I kursen ingår praktik, där man under handledning får arbeta med olika arkivarieuppgifter.", "statlig", 60
```

Comment: What is "right"; what is the output that you desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join method that @joelparkerhenderson talks about just takes the two array value and joins them togheter.

You can use `flatten` to separate and create a new array like this:

```
# Open the CSV for writing
CSV.open("info.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  # Write the entire row all at once
  csv <<  @infodata.values.flatten
end
```

Read more at: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-flatten

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your general question, so perhaps this can help you:

```
# Flatten the titles Array into one String
@infodata[:titles] = @infodata[:titles].join(", ")

# Open the CSV for writing
CSV.open("info.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  # Write the entire row all at once
  csv <<  @infodata.values
end
```

Comment: You might want to add `csv << @infodata.keys` straight after you open the file in order to preserve the headers.

Comment: Please @joelparkerhenderson check the entire code here: https://gist.github.com/2328752 . Should I flatten the hash in the constructor?

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake, you shouldn't `inspect` the `content` before assignment. Simple remove all the `inspect` calls, and flatten the hash just before opening the csv file as suggested by @joelparkerhenderson.

Comment: @Jakobinsky But how to I store the xml value? I have to use inspect.. please check my code on gisthub.